# Where can blender splash scenes be downloaded?

Tags: blend-files

I need the .blend for the blender 2.76 splash screen. If it's available, where can I download it?

Answer (score 4):

The splash for 2.76 comes from the [Alike](https://www.blendernation.com/2016/12/12/short-film-alike/) short. I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you can [download the splash image itself here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/change/master/release/datafiles/splash_2x.png;a9c5e1d9b7927a2d35da05eea0f4e204e8d78fa4). And [browse the history of all splashes here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/master/release/datafiles/splash.png?copies=1). Note that the 2.76 splash was mistakenly labeled as a 2.75 splash, so there *appears* to be two 2.75 splashes and no 2.76 splash.

As far as I know, the source files for Alike aren't available. However, you can find the [sources for more recent splash scenes on the blender cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/57e507b80fcf29412d1f1e53).

Comment: Yeah, and thank you for help and your advice about  2.75 and not at 2.76 however , though ! need to download the the scene not an images.